# Real-time simulation and visualization software

Tags: 3d, simulation

I've been searching for about 2 days for a software that fits my needs for a project I am working on. My need is to simulate the kinematics of a cable-driven parallel robot. Software I thought was suitable was simscape, solidworks motion study, and ansys mechanical. However all these software do not handle cables and are not real time (although not necessary) would be helpful in visualizing the kinematics.
So I am looking for a simulation and visualization software that may feel similar to unity3d.
Basically a physics engine with a user friendly graphical interface (suitable for engineer simulations).
The closest software I have found so far is one called Vortex Studio however it is far too expensive and there is no community version.

I am also aware of

- Adams MSC, however I feel that this software is not user friendly with a large learning curve and seemingly dying community.
- unigine, physics simulations do not seem suitable? I tried their cable physics and was not happy.
- project chrono, bullet physics, not user friendly for quick prototyping.

Comment: Hi I am working a on something similar I am trying to design a Cable driven Continuum Robot can we connect ?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot believe it took me this long to find the software I was looking for.  I'll leave this here for anyone else that falls on this question.

- V-rep
- Gazebo
- Webots

These are simulators for Robotics that has a Unity3d type feel. Although Webots looks good aesthetically, I think I'm going to go with V-rep because it seems easier to work with.

Comment: Links would make this answer better.

Comment: If you're still around, links really would be great!  Thanks!